# Unable to access element of the dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I am trying to access the dropdown's element, html is as follows:

```html
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-3">
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-5" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Select the category of your business.
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-6" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Attractions/Things To Do
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-7" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Bank
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-8" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Bar
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-9" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Book Store
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-10" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Concert Venue
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-11" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Food/Grocery
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-12" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Hotel
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-13" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Local Business
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-14" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Movie Theatre
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-15" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Museum/Art Gallery
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-16" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-17" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Real Estate
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-18" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Restaurant/Cafe
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-19" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>School
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-20" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Shopping/Retail
 </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
 <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-21" role="option">
  <span class="select2-match"></span>Spas/Beauty/Personal Care and many more.
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The code that i am using is:

```
WebElement dr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id =\"select2-chosen-3\"]"));
    dr.click();

 List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"category\"]"));  
        for(WebElement option : options) {
            if(option.getText().trim().contains("Shopping/Retail")) {
                option.click();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it keeps selecting 'Bank' from the drop-down instead of 'Shopping/Retail'

Comment: where is the HTML?

Comment: How did you click on drop down ? I see nothing related to that. That code would work only if you are clicking on drop down. and if you have this ID `category` , then what is the point of using the xpath ?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I copy your HTML code and pasted here but it's not creating any select list, it's creating a html list of options appear in a plain text.

Comment: can you attach UI snap for the dropdown how its look like

Comment: Press the Run code snippet, you would see how HTML appears to us.

Comment: The selectors in the code don't match the html. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand what you are asking. First of all click that select_list, now the drop down will pop up with sets of options, now you write this code immediately after the click of the select_list.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-3']/li/div/span[normalize-space()='Attractions/Things To Do']")).click();
```

If you want to change the element then change the text `Attractions/Things To Do` with your required text, it would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to select your desired element :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-results-3")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-3']//div[contains(.,'Shopping/Retail')]")).click();
```

also you can loop through the all element and once it found the click on that:

```
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('#select2-results-3 li .select2-result-label'));

for(int i=0;i<all.size();i++){
    if(all.get(i).getText().contains("Shopping/Retail")){
    all.get(i).click();
    break;
    }

}
```

Let me know if anything there.

Comment: what if there are two select_lists(which has two different select_list id) having the same options?

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared and your code trials to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Shopping/Retail** once the dropdown is accessed, you can use the following solution:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='select2-results' and @id='select2-results-3']//li[contains(@class,'select2-result-selectable')]/div[@class='select2-result-label'][contains(@id,'select2-result-label-')]"));  
for(WebElement option : options) {
    if(option.getText().contains("Shopping/Retail")) {
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i got caught up with stuff, actually this solution worked for me ==> WebElement dr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id =\"select2-chosen-3\"]"));
dr.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[contains(.,'Restaurant/Cafe')]")).click();

Answer (score 1):

You could select a value from the drop down using below ways:

1) by directly passing the value "Shopping/Retail" using sendkeys() method

2)If above doesn't work use select class:

first inspect the dropdown box and store in a webElement:

```
WebElement business=driver.findElementby*("");
Select dropDown=new Select(business);
```

then you could using three methods:

```
 dd.selectByIndex(14); //seems to be the 15th value in drop down
 dd.selectByText("Shopping/Retail");
```

3).Using actions class

If these didn't workout, post your queries.

Comment: Note that drop down is built using ul and li html tags, select class from selenium can't help you much in this scenario.

Comment: I did not get, what you are trying to communicate. FYI ,this answer is prone to downvote.

Comment: oh if thats the cases then, pass the option in Xpath only:                                         
     driver.findElementByXpath("ul[@role='listbox']/li[15]/following-sibling::span");                                                                                                           require more clarity on the   dom